# Modifying text in latex figure

Tags: examples

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\begin{document}
\begin{example}
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.40,
       thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=blue,
         thick,
         inner sep=2pt,
         minimum size=0.cm,scale=0.65
       }
     ] 




           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{1}]{}; 


           \node (a6) at (1.5,0) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{6}]{};
           \node (a7) at (3,1) [acteur,label=above:\scriptsize{7}]{};
           \node (a8) at (4.5,2) [acteur,label=right:\scriptsize{8}]{};
           \node (a9) at (3,-1) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{9}]{};
           \node (a10) at (4.5,-2) [acteur,label=right:\scriptsize{10}]{};

           \node (a2) at (-1.5,1) [acteur,label=above:\scriptsize{2}]{};
           \node (a3) at (-3,2) [acteur,label=left:\scriptsize{3}]{};
           \node (a4) at (-1.5,-1) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{4}]{};
           \node (a5) at (-3,-2) [acteur,label=left:\scriptsize{5}]{};
           \node at (-5.5,3) {\textit{$T$}};
            \draw  (a1) -- (a6);
            \draw  (a6) -- (a7);
            \draw  (a7) -- (a8);
            \draw  (a6) -- (a9);
            \draw  (a9) -- (a10);
            \draw  (a1) -- (a2);
            \draw  (a2) -- (a3);
            \draw  (a1) -- (a4);
            \draw  (a4) -- (a5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{ A tree having property $\mathcal{R_E}$}\label{fig2}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{example}
\end{document}


How I can place the example1 in above in left corner?
```

Comment: Could you please mak your code compilable. How is the `example` environment defined?

Comment: Now it will execute correctly

Comment: Use `\quad` after `\begin{example}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\quad` after `\begin{example}` like:

```
\begin{example}
\quad
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
```

or `~` after `\begin{example}` like:

```
\begin{example}~
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
```

[image]